# PHP summing variables from while loop

Tags: php, mysql, sum

I'm making a simple webpage to keep my company records of how many stuff we bought and I ran into a small problem. I have this code:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM lisicara WHERE (datum BETWEEN '$a' AND '$b') ORDER BY datum ASC");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $datum = $row['datum'];
    $kg_kupljeno = $row['kg_kupljeno'];
    $cena1 = $row['cena1'];
    $kg_prodato = $row['kg_prodato'];
    $cena2 = $row['cena2'];
    $napomena = $row['napomena'];

    $ukupno1 = $kg_kupljeno * $cena1;
    $ukupno2 = $kg_prodato * $cena2;
    $razlika = $ukupno2 - $ukupno1;

    echo '
        <tr>
            <td>'.$datum.'</td>
            <td>'.number_format($kg_kupljeno).'</td>
            <td>'.number_format($cena1).'</td>
            <td>'.number_format($ukupno1).'</td>
            <td>'.number_format($kg_prodato).'</td>
            <td>'.number_format($cena2).'</td>
            <td>'.number_format($ukupno2).'</td>
            <td>'.number_format($razlika).'</td>
            <th>'.$napomena.'</th>
        </tr>';
}
```

After this while loop it shows a tr where it sums all from table. Problem is that `$ukupno1`, `$ukupno2` and `$razlika` are not displaying from database but they are calculating with PHP `$ukupno1 = $kg_kupljeno * $cena1`.

How to sum all `$ukupno1` and display it after the while loop?

Comment: You can try to define another variable as `$ukupno1sum` and on every `while` loop, add `$ukupno1sum += $ukupno1`

Comment: Warning! Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection Attacks!

Answer (score 0):

Declare a variable outsite the loop then manipulate that variable inside the while loop then use it after the while loop.

**Example:**

```
//Declaration
$total_ukupno1 =0;

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM lisicara WHERE (datum BETWEEN '$a' AND '$b') ORDER BY datum ASC");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $datum = $row['datum'];
    $kg_kupljeno = $row['kg_kupljeno'];
    $cena1 = $row['cena1'];
    $kg_prodato = $row['kg_prodato'];
    $cena2 = $row['cena2'];
    $napomena = $row['napomena'];

    $ukupno1 = $kg_kupljeno * $cena1;
    $ukupno2 = $kg_prodato * $cena2;
    $razlika = $ukupno2 - $ukupno1;

    //add ukupno1 or manipulate the variable
    $total_ukupno1 += $ukupno1;
    echo '
        <tr>
            <td>'.$datum.'</td>
            <td>'.number_format($kg_kupljeno).'</td>
            <td>'.number_format($cena1).'</td>
            <td>'.number_format($ukupno1).'</td>
            <td>'.number_format($kg_prodato).'</td>
            <td>'.number_format($cena2).'</td>
            <td>'.number_format($ukupno2).'</td>
            <td>'.number_format($razlika).'</td>
            <th>'.$napomena.'</th>
        </tr>';
}

//display after the loop
echo $total_ukupno1;
```

I hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

To get a running total of `$ukupno1`, add the following before the while loop:

```
$ukupno1Total = 0;
```

And then inside the loop, add the individual amounts to the total.  Put this after `$ukupno1 = $kg_kupljeno * $cena1;`

```
$ukupno1Total = $ukupno1Total + $ukupno1;
```

And then after the loop, display `$ukupno1Total`

Answer (score 0):

Zdravo brate!

Replace this code:

```
$ukupno1 = $kg_kupljeno * $cena1;
$ukupno2 = $kg_prodato * $cena2;
$razlika = $ukupno2 - $ukupno1;
```

With this code:

```
$ukupno1 += $kg_kupljeno * $cena1;
$ukupno2 += $kg_prodato * $cena2;
$razlika = $ukupno2 - $ukupno1;
```

and add this to your declaration:

```
//Declaration
$total_ukupno1 =0;
$ukupno1 = 0;
$ukupno2 = 0;
```

With this modification, you will obtain the total bought (ukupno1) and the total sold (ukupno2) on the last line. You will also have the benefit of having the amount sold inbetween the two dates `$a` and `$b`.

Let me know if that worked for you.